# Django - filter manytomany field - request.LANGUAGE_CODE

Tags: django, many-to-many

I've been experiencing a problem with filter and m2m relation and request.LANGUAGE_CODE.

If in a view I use request.LANGUAGE_CODE in first example the query returns all possible entries for each available language.

While in second model everything works perfectly.

Example - not working:

Model:

```
 class Publisher(models.Model):
     publication = models.ManyToManyField('Translation', related_name="")
```

View:

```
pub = Publisher.objects.filter(publication__language=request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

Example - working:

Model:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Tytuł", blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Treść", blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=settings.LANGUAGES, default=settings.LANGUAGES[1])
```

View:

```
 pub = Publisher.objects.filter(language=request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

How does that work and how to fix or avoid that issue?

Answer (score 0):

The language attribute is part of Translation objects in the first example, and part of Publisher in the second one. Also, in the first one Publisher has no text of its own, but references M2M to Translation objects which hold the text.

So in the first example you are asking it to select Publishers, not Translations (which are linked by the member publication). So if any Publisher has *any* Translation object in the queried language, you will get that Publisher, and then when you do something like pub.publication.all() it will do what you are asking: It will return EVERY publication object associated with that Publisher of any language.

To fix the first example you need to do something like

```
pub = Translation.objects.filter(language=request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

if you just want a list of all articles in a certain language, because the Translation objects have the text and the language setting data, not the Publisher.

If you want a list of all articles in a specific language from one specific publisher, add another filter variable, like:

```
pub = Translation.objects.filter(language=request.LANGUAGE_CODE, publisher=publisher_id)
```

or whatever way you want to identify that specific publisher (and setting related_name="" is a bad idea, because then you cannot make a reverse relationship at all).

Also, I would change the relationship of Publisher.publication to ForeignKey, because unless you have a situation where more than one Publisher is working together with another Publisher on the same article, you don't need M2M, you need O2M (one Publisher writes many publications/Translations).